# .NET WinForms KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress: effect of setting it to True in the KeyUp event

Tags: .net, winforms, keypress, keydown, suppress

The [KeyEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs) class in WinForms implements the Boolean [SuppressKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress) property. `KeyEventArgs` provides data for the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events. The `SuppressKeyPress` property can be set to True in a `KeyDown` event handler to suppress the subsequent `KeyPress` event - this purpose is clear. But is there any effect of setting `SuppressKeyPress` to True in event handlers of the `KeyUp` event?

Comment: No.  It prevents the KeyPress event from firing.  But it already fired by the time KeyUp is detected.

Comment: @HansPassant, I didn't understand the second sentence. Can we read `SuppressKeyPress` in KeyUp or what? If not and `SuppressKeyPress` makes sense only in `KeyDown`, wouldn't it be better to provide a special EventArgs class for `KeyDown` and implement `SuppressKeyPress` only in it?

Comment: The normal order of events is KeyDown => KeyPress => KeyUp.  So KeyPress already fired before you can *write* the SuppressKeyPress property in a KeyUp event handler, there is no time machine.  But it is technically possible to read these notifications out of order by pinvoking PeekMessage, just as it is technically possible to juggle chainsaws.  Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues) if you violently disagree.

Comment: Setting `SuppressKeyPress = true` when a *physical* Key is down, suppresses the key entered, so KeyPress is not raised (assuming it would raise for that Key). Setting it in the *physical* Key release has no effect on the Key Pressed, because `WM_CHAR`, `WM_SYSCHAR` messages have already been processed -- `SuppressKeyPress = true` causes a call to `PeekMessage()` with `PM_REMOVE` -- The EventArgs is the same because the internal method that handles both is the same

Comment: @Jimi, I analyzed the WinForms source code and tried to find the answer myself. I did find the `ProcessKeyEventArgs` method in which `RemovePendingMessages` (read `PeekMessage`) you mentioned is called when `SuppressKeyPress = true`. Is it that "internal method that handles both" you mentioned? Can you point me in the right direction? IMHO, a better object design would be to create an ancestor from `KeyEventArgs` for the `KeyDown` event and provide `SuppressKeyPress` only in this class. That "internal method" could simply work with the parent, i.e. `KeyEventArgs`.

Comment: When WndProc receives a message, any of `WM_CHAR`, `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP` (or the `_SYS` variants), the message is passed to either `ProcessKeyMessage()` or DefWndProc. If the former processes the message, or the Parent handles the key press in preview, DefWndProc is not called (hence the target Control doesn't receive the message). After that, the main dispatcher - `ProcessKeyEventArgs()` -  is called. When the message is either `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP`, a new KeyEventArgs is created, then the corresponding event is raised (calling either `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp`)

Comment: The `WM_CHAR` / `WM_SYSCHAR` message is received before `WM_KEYUP`, so only SuppressKeyPress on `WM_KEYDOWN` is useful to suppress a logical Key, because the key has not been processed yet, so you can PeekMessage it out. In `WM_KEYUP`, the key has already been dispatched to the target Control (if not handled in preview or on KeyDown). The fact that `KeyEventArgs` is the same Type of object in both `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` is just contextual / for convenience. You know you cannot suppress a Key that has already been dispatched when `WM_KEYUP` is received. Not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: @Jimi, I just needed a confirmation that `SuppressKeyPress` is completely useless in the `KeyUp` event. You've confirmed it - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with all commenters that `SuppressKeyPress` is absolutely useless in `KeyUp`. As @Jimi explained, this field appears in `KeyUp` only because of the specific internal architecture of the [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control) class.